# Turn list of lists into dataframe in most efficient way in R

Tags: r

I want to turn a list of lists into a dataframe where each name(listoflists) is a different column name. It is a VERY big list so I want to do this in the **most efficient way possible**.

```
listoflists=list(c(1,2,3,4),c(5,6,7,8))
names(listoflists) <- c("col1", "col2")
```

What could I do to get the following results:

```
 print(df)
 col1     col2
  1        5
  2        6
  3        7
  4        8
```

Comment: Note that `listoflists` is not a list of lists.  It is a list of numeric vectors.  `list(list(1,2,3,4),list(5,6,7,8))` would be a list of lists.

Comment: Does the list elements have the same length

Answer (score 2):

We can wrap with `data.frame`

```
data.frame(listoflists)
```

-output

```
   col1 col2
1    1    5
2    2    6
3    3    7
4    4    8
```

In case the OP meant, it as a nested `list`, then `unlist` the inner list element by looping over the `lapply` and wrap with `data.frame`

```
data.frame(lapply(listoflists, unlist))
```

---

If it should be most efficient way, then `setDT` can be applied as well

```
library(data.table)
setDT(listoflists)
```

-output

```
> listoflists
   col1 col2
1:    1    5
2:    2    6
3:    3    7
4:    4    8
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `!!!` operator with tibble. Some examples:

```r
library(tidyverse)

#first case
listoflists1=list(c(1,2,3,4),c(5,6,7,8)) %>%
  set_names(c("col1", "col2"))

tibble(!!!listoflists1)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>    col1  col2
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     5
#> 2     2     6
#> 3     3     7
#> 4     4     8

#second case
listoflists2=list(list(1:4),list(5:8)) %>%
  set_names(c("col1", "col2"))

tibble(!!!listoflists2) %>%
  unnest(names(.))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>    col1  col2
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1     1     5
#> 2     2     6
#> 3     3     7
#> 4     4     8


#third case
listoflists3=list(list(1,2,3,4),list(5,6,7,8)) %>% set_names(c("col1", "col2"))

tibble(!!!listoflists3) %>%
  unnest(names(.))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>    col1  col2
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     5
#> 2     2     6
#> 3     3     7
#> 4     4     8

#it is possible to use unnest without cols argument but it will throw a warning message.
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can use `list2DF`.

```
list2DF(listoflists)
#  col1 col2
#1    1    5
#2    2    6
#3    3    7
#4    4    8
```

What will also work with a list of lists and not only with a list of numeric vectors.

```
x <- list(list(1,2,3,4),list(5,6,7,8))
names(x) <- c("col1", "col2")
list2DF(x)
#  col1 col2
#1    1    5
#2    2    6
#3    3    7
#4    4    8
```

If all list elements have the same length, an efficient but **not recommended** way might be:

```
class(listoflists) <- "data.frame"
attr(listoflists, "row.names") <- .set_row_names(length(listoflists[[1]]))
listoflists
#  col1 col2
#1    1    5
#2    2    6
#3    3    7
#4    4    8
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(listoflists)

# A tibble: 4 x 2
   col1  col2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     5
2     2     6
3     3     7
4     4     8
```

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use external libraries for some reason you can create a `data.frame` as follows:

```r
out_df <- do.call(data.frame, listoflists)
```

If you want a faster implementation of `data.frame` you can use the `data.table` package instead.

```r
library(data.table)
out_dt <- do.call(data.table, listoflists)
```

However the `setDT` proposed by @arkun should be faster in this case as it doesn't make a copy of the data.

**N.B.** My solutions work correctly only if your input is actually a list of vectors not when if it is a list of lists.